# Setting up website with multiple directories in Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I currently have my index.html file within a public_html folder and my PHP config files in a separate resource folder which is on the same level at the public_html folder. When setting up my Homestead.yaml file, I have to point to the exact directory where my index.html folder is. This is causing issues when I need to call a script from the other folder. Have I set up my folders wrong, or is my yaml file wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What does your `index.html` file have to do with Laravel? It uses an `index.php` file inside of your `public` directory, where your site's files will be served from. You can place the `index.php` inside of your `public_html` directory and have your yaml file point to the `/path/to/the/app/public_html` directory and it will work the same way. This would assume, of course, that your code would then reside in `/path/to/the/app`.

Comment: can you please mention your Homestead.yaml file.